# Why is "sys.argv" not available in Sublime API?

Tags: python, sublimetext2

This question was already [asked](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=8943) on Sublime Forum, but it seems no one can answer it. Maybe you can?

I've got the same issue on Windows 7 and 8, Sublime 2.0.1 x86 version:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./sublime_plugin.py", line 362, in run_
File "./myTestPlugin.py", line 8, in run
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'argv'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because sublime plugins are *not* scripts. There is no command line, so there are no command line arguments to parse.

Python, in Sublime, is embedded, and for embedded python code to have `sys.argv` set, Sublime would have to set the arguments explicitly. See [Intro to embedding Python](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/intro.html#embedding-python).

If you feel strongly about this, you'd have to make a case with the Sublime Text 2 developer to add a [`PySys_SetArgvEx(argc, argv, updatepath)`](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#PySys_SetArgvEx) call after [`Py_Initialize()`](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#Py_Initialize).

Answer (score 0):

Using Package Control

1. Install this sublime text 2/3 package via Package Control;
2. Search for package: `"InputArgs"`
   or,

OSX:

```
$ cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ <2/3>/Packages/
$ git clone git://github.com/bilalba/InputArgs.git InputArgs
```

Linux (Ubuntu like distros):

```
$ cd ~/.config/sublime-text-<2/3>/Packages/
$ git clone git://github.com/bilalba/InputArgs.git InputArgs
```

Windows:

Copy the directory to:

```
"C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text <2/3>\Packages"
```